# In neo4j, how to traversal a disconnected graph using JAVA API？

Tags: neo4j, traversal, java

From `neo4j` manual, i know how to use Traversal Framework.
But when my graph in `Neo4j` is disconnected, i do not know how to traversal all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done using the traversal framework. You can reach all nodes by using GlobalGraphOperations.at( db ).getAllNodes(). http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.3/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html

Answer (score 0):

Traversal generally assumes that the nodes are connected; traversal refers to going over some set of relationships.  If you can't get from A to B via relationships, then you can't reach them both in the same traversal.

[This method in the Java API](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.3/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllNodes%28%29) will let you go through every single node in the entire database, but it won't assume any order.

So it depends on your requirements.  One way to do this might be to start matching nodes (i.e. `MATCH n RETURN n` in cypher, or using the method above).  Use each node you encounter as the basis for a traversal over all relationships.   Keep a list of node IDs you have already encountered.   As you return from traversing one set of nodes, (back to the full list you're iterating through slowly), then skip any nodes coming back from the total list that you've already visited via traversal.

So, in pseudo-code, something like this:

```
HashSet<Long> seenIds = new HashSet<Long>();
for(Node n : allNodesInDatabase) { 
    if(seenIds.contains(n.getId()) continue;
    traverse(n);
} 

function traverse(n) { 
   // Use traversal framework to walk all relationships in/out of "n".
   // Update "seenIds" with anything the traversal framework sees.
}
```

This will discover all "disconnected subgraphs" and both ensure that you touch everything in the database, but that it's done via some traversal order you define.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Since there are so many nodes in this graph, i can't put them all in the memory.Now i am trying to filter some useless nodes and make the graph smaller.